# Not able execute one perticular feature file using command line in selenium cucumber script

Tags: selenium, webdriver, cucumber

I am using Cucumber 1.1.1 and am having problems running a single feature.

Am able to include exclude tags by using command

mvn install -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/featureFiles --tags @NounImport,@~ElementSearch"

When am executing feature file which doesn't contain any tags.
like
mvn install -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/featureFiles/CommonFeature/Commonfeatures.feature"
with this command executed all scenarios which are there with specific tags in another feature file also and along with this feature file.

And tags are executing in alfabeticle order only. How can i execute in my order with tags.
So any one can suggest me how to run one perticular feature file from command line and how to declare tags in order.

Answer (score 1):

If I were just running 1 features I would run
`cucumber --name "<Feature Name>"`. If you need a specific order, make a ruby script that says something like this:

```
features = []
features << "<Feature 1 name>"
features << "<Feature 2 name>"

features.each.with_index do |feature,index|
  cmd = "cd <cucumber directory>;"
  cmd += "cucumber --name \"#{feature}\""
  system(cmd) #or to save: @output ||= []; output << `cmd`
end
```

Read the cucumber wiki for other help: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Running-Features